# Special Relativity - When and where did the rod start moving?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

In the below figure,

[image: Diagram for the above question]

A rigid rod is at rest. End point $A$ and $B$ are at $x=0$ and $x=1$ respectively.
At $T=0$, in an instant $A$ starts moving at velocity $+v$. i.e. coordinate of this event i.e. A starts moving is $(0,0)$

Question: What is the $(x,t)$ coordinate when $B$ starts moving.

Let us assume answer is $(x_0,t_0)$

I think $t_{0} = 0$ as rod is rigid hence at any instant both the ends should move at same velocity. (As velocity of $A$ at $t=0$ is $v$ so $B$ will have same velocity as well).

And, $x_{0}<1$ due to length contraction.

So if I write x coordinates of points A and B, then:

$$x_{A} = 0\,\,\text{for}\,\, t<0\,;\, x_{A} = vt\,\, \text{for}\,\, t>0$$

$$x_B = 1\,\, \text{for}\,\, t<0\,;\, x_B=(x_0 + v(t-t_0))\,\, \text{for}\,\, t>t_0$$ I am unable to understand what happens to B between $t=0$ and $t=t_0$

I have two questions:

Q1: I think I'm wrong in writing the equations for $x$-coordinate of $B$. What will the correct equations be? What is the correct value of $(x_0,t_0)$?

Q2: Think if you were a local observer at $x=1$. For such an observer $B$'s motion cannot be discontinuous. It can't just suddenly disappear from $x=1$ and appear at $x=x_0$. Isn't it? Am I right there?

*A few answers below talk of a second reference frame. Please note in this question we are not talking of any second reference frame. Only reference frame is the one in which the rod AB was at rest initially. Basically the question is to draw the world lines of points A and B with respect to this reference frame.
And yes rod AB accelerates - but SR doesn't restrict physical bodies to not change their velocities. So we should get well defined world-lines for point A and point B basis all the initial conditions provided in the question*

*This is not a homework question. I'm trying to understand special relativity and I have been thinking about these situations. (And I think I'm lacking any intuitive understanding of SR whatsoever and often confusion between space and time coordinates and their joint behavior)*

Thanks for your help

Comment: Response to your edit:  If you're only interested in one reference frame, then length contraction is irrelevant.  (Length contraction invovles a comparison between measurements in different frames.)   You are right that it would be very weird and unphysical to assume that the endpoint jumps from $x=1$ to some other location discontinuously.  So the answer to your question is that the movement of $B$ starts at $x=1$ and at whatever time you choose to assume it starts.  (If you want to assume it starts simultaneously with the movement of $A$, then that time is $t=0$.)

Comment: so take a unit rod at rest initially in a RF (call it RF1) and start accelerating slowly unto velocity v. so are you saying in RF1 this rod length won't exhibit length contraction? doesn't seem right to me

Comment: If "exhibit length contraction" is your way of saying"shrink", then --- provided both ends of the rod start moving at the same time with the same velocity --- of course it doesn't shrink.  You don't need relativity to see this, and you don't even really need physics.  It's just an immediate consequence of the motion you've postulated.  If you postulate some other motion, you might get a different answer.

Comment: (But of course you should not say "exhibit length contraction" in the first place if what you mean is "shrink".  Your rod does not shrink but it does exhibit length contraction in the sense that there is a discrepancy between the (unchanged) length in the original frame and the (new) length in the rod's new rest frame.)

Comment: Also, since you've now got your answer, and since the answer is obvious anyway, I won't be responding to any more followups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a rigid rod.

That's putting it brutally.  In ordinary mechanics the rigid rod is as familiar as the frictionless pulley and the massless string: it's a very common concept, and we understand what it means even though it can't be achieved in practice, it's useful as an ideal.  Part of the intuitive understanding of SR that you seek is that the phrase 'rigid rod', like the word 'simultaneously', rings an alarm bell.

(The 'rigid rods' used in some definitions of length are 'rigid' only in the sense that their length is (defined as) being the same provided they are at rest: if they are moving/accelerating their length may be different.)

So $t_0$ depends on the speed of sound along the rod, but it cannot be less than $1/c$

Comment: Yes indeed I have been reading about this and had kind of guessed the concept of rigidity needs to be redefined. I now realize to answer this question you need to know/assume the material properties of the rod - and as you say information speed along the rod can't go faster than 'c'. Many thanks

Comment: It is indeed very counter-intuitive that the length of the 'rigid' (in Newton world) rod will vary and gradually settle at the 'Lorentz contracted length'. I think this lack of intuition makes SR difficult.

Comment: Be careful, there is no "shrinking" to a  'Lorentz contracted length'.  Length contraction does not apply to any physical object; the "contracted" object is smeared over time in the observer's frame.  That is how all the ladder and pole "paradoxes" come about.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you stated there's no second reference frame; we have to assume there's one (moving with respect to the rest frame) in order for your question to be consistent. We got two different cases.

$1.$ Two ends of the rod may start moving simultaneously in the moving frame, but not simultaneous in rest frame. This basically means:

$$\Delta x=(\Delta x'+v\Delta t')\gamma$$
$$\Delta t'=0$$
$$\Delta t\neq 0$$

We can be sure that in your original frame $A$ and $B$ may start moving at different times. Take the this $t_B$ for end $B$.
$$\Delta x=(\Delta x')\gamma$$
So the coordinates are $(1,t_B)$.

$2.$ Both $\Delta t$ and $\Delta t'$ are $0$. We mean that in your original frame and moving frame they start moving simultaneously. But this means;

$$\Delta x=\Delta x'$$

Frames are coincident in this case because the length of the rod doesn't change. And $t_B$ is $0$. Coordinates are $(1,0).$

Answer (score -1):

Your question is:

> What is the (x,t) coordinate when B starts moving?

You are the only person in the world who can answer this question, because you are the person who is inventing this scenario.  The only reason I know that $A$ starts moving at $(0,0)$ is because you told me so.  If I want to know at what event $B$ starts moving, all I can do is ask you.

Let's write $F$ and $G$ for the frames of the "stationary" and "moving" rods (stationary and moving are of course relative to the observers, say you and me).

If you want to assume that the length of the rod never changes in frame F, then you must assume that $B$ starts moving at $t=0,x=1$, simultaneously with the event where $A$ starts moving.  Then in frame $G$, $B$ starts moving before $A$ does, so in frame $G$ the rod becomes longer.

Or, if you want to assume that the length of the rod never changes in frame G, then you must assume that the two ends start moving at the same time in frame G.  In that case, $A$ starts moving before $B$ in frame $F$, so in frame $F$, the rod shrinks.

What you cannot assume is that the length of the rod remains unchanged in both frames, which is what your use of the word "rigidity" suggests.   You have to make up  your mind whether the rod is going to stretch in frame $G$ or shrink in frame $F$.

So step one is to clarify your assumption.  Then the answer to your question will be a simple calculation.

Comment: As per question above - that A  starts moving at (0,0) is the given of the problem. You can also consider this as an assumption. AB is rigid is the other given. I think the question is well framed - and asking the (x,t) coordinates when B starts moving is a valid Q and has a fixed answer - Just that I'm unable to work it out

Comment: The meaning of "rigid" is unclear.  The obvious interpretation is "the length of the rod does not change".  But the length of the rod must change in one frame or the other, so the assumption is quite unclear until you **specify** the frame in which you are assuming the length to be fixed.    Again, you are the only person who can clarify this.  If by "rigid" you mean "length unchanged in frame $F$", you'll get one answer.  If you mean "length unchanged in frame $G$", you'll get another.  Which do you mean?

Comment: In any event, your joint assumptions that (in frame $F$) the right end of the rod is present at both $t=0,x=0$ and at $t=0,x_0<0$ are clearly not compatible.

Comment: for me rigid is rigid in "physical" sense. if i were to define rigid - i will define it as length doesn't change in any reference frame. (i.e. length is invariant - whatever it is in a particular RF it remains the same whenever you measure it in that particular RF)

Comment: left end is present at x=0 not the right end

Comment: Sorry, I meant your assumptions that the right end is present at both $t=0,x=1$ and $t=0, x_0<1$.

Comment: And hence my question - I know I'm wrong some where - but where? so what is (x0,t0) as per you? It can be clearly derived in my opinion from the facts in the Q

Comment: If you are defining "rigid" to mean "length doesn't change in any reference frame" then your rod does not exist.  Before it starts moving, its lengths in $F$ and $G$ are equal.  After it's moving, its lengths in $F$ and $G$ are different.  Its length in at least one frame must change.  Which frame it changes in is entirely up to you, as the creator of the scenario.

Comment: no that is not my understanding - as per me initial conditions of the problem are given and based on SR we should be able to come up at exact values - it is not dependent to me

Comment: @aman_cc What you describe for rigid in a "physical" sense is rigid in a non-relativistic sense.  Its a sense which is meaningful in Newtonian physics.  When you get to relativistic speeds, some concepts which made sense at slow speeds stop being meaningful.  "Rigid" is one of those concepts.  It breaks down at high speeds.  Another more tangible example of rules breaking down, is the rule that the sum of the angles of a triangle must add up to 180, which is true on a flat sheet of paper, but not true on the surface of a globe.

Comment: Another example is the continuous idea of "pressure" in a fluid, which works well up until you have shock waves, and then it gets murky real fast!

Comment: @CortAmmon - Thanks. Yes - more I think about this more I'm convinced that my understanding of "rigid" body needs some change in SR. Are you able to draw the world lines of A and B?