# Special Relativity - World Lines (for rigid bodies)

Tags: special-relativity, rigid-body-dynamics

S is an inertial reference frame with origin at O.

A unit ***rigid**** rod AB is at rest with respect to S. A and B are end-points of the rod.

$xA=0$  and  $xB=1$

At $t=1$, point A start accelerating towards right with a constant acceleration of '***a***' until time $t = 2$. After that point A stops the acceleration and continues to the right with a constant velocity

Question: Draw the world-lines/space-time diagrams for point **A** and point **B** as observed in S?

Please see the figure below for an illustration of the problem

Please note:

1. All measurements are with respect to S. In the problem there is no other reference-frame that we are considering or are interested in
2. *By ***rigid*** - I mean in a physical sense or as we know it in Newtonian mechanics. I'm not sure how it translates in SR framework. (and I guess that is what makes this Q interesting for me. While world-line of point A seems trivial I think I'm struggling with world line for point B *especially when does the acceleration for B start and when does it end*)

[image: Illustration]

Comment: In addition to being homework-like, this question was already asked (by the same person) and answered here, just yesterday:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/566347/special-relativity-when-and-where-did-the-rod-start-moving

Comment: @WillO This is NOT homework - I don't attend school. I thought this situation to understand SR better. If you see carefully this and other Q I asked have a difference - the other Q had infinite acceleration or a jerk - This one has a smooth change in velocity. Also I have defined things more precisely based on some responses I got to the older Q. Anyways see my answer below - to the best of my current knowledge it is about defining "rigidity" in SR which is a non-trivial problem. Do realize A and B are 'connected' and cannot just move independently - and that is the fundamental idea of this Q

Comment: @Willo - Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/566688/special-relativity-and-rigid-bodies It would be nice if you can help me there if you have a specific answer to that question

Answer (score 3):

Rigid bodies **cannot exist** in special relativity, because a rigid body implies that force is transmitted instantaneously throughout the body. That said, I think that the question intends "rigid body" to mean that point B starts and stops its acceleration at the same moment as point A, in the rest frame of point A.

Comment: Thanks. No I specifically defined rigid rod as 'rigid' as per Newtonian concept. So basis whatever information is given (so only the information about point A is given in the Q) - can't I draw the world line of point B? We can surely perform this experiment and measure the space-time coordinates of point B - or this experiment is not possible?

Comment: @aman_cc What do you mean by "as per Newtonian concept"? The "Newtonian concept" of a rigid rod that I'm familiar with involves instantaneous transmission of force throughout the rigid body (if this wasn't true, then you could sharply tap on the corner of a rigid body and it would deform before the rest of the body "caught up with it"). This is impossible in special relativity.

Comment: so my understanding of Newtonian rigidity is distance between any 2 points remains same. This then leads into instantaneous transmission of force - which is clearly wrong in SR. Hence I need some better/more general definition of 'rigidity' in SR. So I thought of the scenario that I present in the Q above. I feel (intuitively) that this experiment can be performed in real world and hence I can measure space-time ordinates of B. Can I therefore derive them from the theory of SR and a more general (and new) definition of rigidity? Hope I'm making sense.